# ssh Help logging to remote VMware

Tags: server, ssh, vmware, openssh, kali

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aXz5.jpg Can anyone help me figure out that I am doing wrong here? I am trying to remotely login to another virtual machine.

Comment: Can you ping this ip? this picture show that you aren't in the same network

Comment: I apologize I am fairly new to this. What do you mean by ping?

Comment: You can made `ping 172.16.184.140` this check if you can see the this ip from this machin and show the response and you can do two `ìfconfig` to show the network configuration

Comment: In the picture you show that you are starting the ssh server in this machine and you are try to connect a remote ip

Comment: I ping that and again said "Network is unreachable".

Comment: All right, you aren't in the same network you can check this with `ifconfig`

Comment: How do I make it the same network?

Comment: You have 2 machines? I said you that your start ssh server in your local machine( Kali) and you are trying to connect another machine, i don't understand this, would you like to connect a remote machine or the same machine? If you like to connect another machine you not need to start ssh server in local machine. If you can to connect a remote machine in this IP you have to change config of ethernet to put 2 machines in the same subnetwork, for this you can use graphical interface to modify the ethernet configuration

Comment: I want to use Kali to remotely log into another machine.

Comment: I will look up how to configure the ethernet.

Comment: You can use a command to make this `ifconfig eth0 <newIP> netmask <netmask> up`

Comment: Perfect! You are helping me so much! Thank you! Only problem now is that the password I use for the other machine does not work here: http://imgur.com/SA4laJq

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and its official derivatives as posted on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors **so Kali is off-topic here.** However, on [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at all varieties of Linux and Unix, especially if you use the *Kali-Linux* tag.  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

The machines aren't in the same network, you have to change you client ethernet config to put in the same network, you can user a command like this

```
# ifconfig eth0 <newIP> netmask <netmask> up
```

Like you comment, you have problems with password to connect, you can see what problem in log file

```
nano /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: This is the result: http://imgur.com/Rw0C6nV